# Do I need to level shift the PWM signal from a Raspberry Pi Pico for regular RC servo?

Tags: arduino, pwm, servo, level-shifting, logic-level

I am trying to control regular SG90 servo with a Raspberry Pi Pico. My problem is that those servos produce maximum torque while powered by voltage between 4.8V to 6V (5V is optimal for me.)

I powered the servo with an external power supply and connected the signal wire to one of Pico's GPIO pins. I produced a PWM signal on the pin using th Arduino Servo library, but the motion of the servo is very slow and shaky compared to regular 5V Arduino Nano board doing the same task.

Do I have to level shift the PWM signal to also correspond to 5V logic? If so, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you done a search here about level shifting?

Comment: Did you remember to connect the power supply ground to the Pico ground?

Comment: Yes I did connect them :D